# QEntities are not generated

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

I created a spring boot project but QEntities are not generated. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this? Thanks.

The error that I get is:
`QAppello cannot be resolved to a type`.
Appello is an entity of my project and AppelloRepository is its repository.
I tried to post in pom many dependencies that i found out in internet but nothing worked out.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.iuni_datamodel</groupId>
    <artifactId>iuni_datamodel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>iuni_datamodel</name>
    <description>data model </description>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
            <classifier>jpa</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source />
                    <target />
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <!--Plugin for query-dsl-->
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                       <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Appello.java  (entity)

```
package com.iuni_datamodel.Appello;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


// Data annotation
@QueryEntity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
// Code generation annotation
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Appello implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(length = 16)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    private Date dataInizio;
    private Date dataFine;

}


    /* 
List<GameVersion> gameVersions = new JPAQuery(em)
    .select()
    .from()
    .leftJoin()
    .fetchJoin()
    .fetch();

for(GameVersion gameVersion : gameVersons){
    gameversion.getGameversionPlayModes();

}
*/
```

AppelloRepository.java

```
package com.iuni_datamodel.Appello;


import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBinderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBindings;


public interface AppelloRepository extends JpaRepository<Appello, UUID>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Appello>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QAppello> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QAppello root) {
         
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in intellij you have to right click your pom.xml file and select maven > generate sources. After a few seconds that the loading is finished, you must run a maven `clean and compile` command. Afterwards, if there are no errors, you may run your project and the QClasses should be generated.

Answer (score -1):

Usually I use vscode but I tried with intellij but I can't clean and build maven because when I try to open effective pom I get an error

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.